Understanding certain boundary conditions of functionals of the form $\int_{p_0}^{p_1}f(x,y)\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$
A question I had whilst reading section 15 of Fomin's "Calculus of Variations" (great book btw!!)

The General Question:
Among all smooth curves whose end points $p_0$,$p_1$ lie between two curves $y=\phi(x)$ and $y=\psi(x)$, find the curve for which the functional:
$J[y]=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}F(x,y,y')dx$
Has an extremum.
Now, when $F(x,y,y')$ has the form $f(x,y)\sqrt{1+y'^2}$, the boundary relations imposed by the problem reduce to the conditions that:
$y' = -\frac{1}{\phi'}$
for the left hand point and
$y' = -\frac{1}{\psi'}$
for the right hand point. i.e., for functionals of the form $\int_{p_0}^{p_1}f(x,y)\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$, the boundary condition reduces to orthogonality.

Can somebody give me an intuitive reason why I would expect that for functionals of the form $\int_{p_0}^{p_1}f(x,y)\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$, the curve that is an extremal will always approach the boundary curves orthogonally? Perhaps it would help if somebody could give me an example of a physical system where this type of boundary condition is being applied.
This is very surprising to me as $\int_{p_0}^{p_1}f(x,y)\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$ is a very large class of functionals! The $\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ means that we are integrating with respecting to arc length.
